# How to place Buy/Sell order on market execution

Tags: python-3.x, bots, metatrader5, back-testing

I am backtesting my code using backtesting in Python 3 and I am using self.buy or self.sell to open a new position but it use to open my position 8 points ahead of given buy/sell level but I want to execute order at the current level like Market Execution order in MT5.

What I understand by this that self.buy or self.sell function is used for limit orders only but not for market execution orders.

How can I write right code for market execution orders?